# How to display controller action view in blockUI

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, blockui

I am trying to set blockUI message to display controller action view. I have tried everything but it doesn't display anything.
I have tried something like this:

```
$.blockUI({
             message: $('MyController/MyAction'), // I also need to pass some parameters here
        css: {
        top: ($(window).height() - 600) / 2 + 'px',
        left: ($(window).width() - 600) / 2 + 'px',
        width: '600px'
        }
        });
```

What I am trying to make is image display like on facebook for my image gallery. And I have a view that contains Image/Comments/Back/Next but I failed to display it in modal form.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the correct way to call an ajax method :=)

```
$('MyController/MyAction')
```

jQuery is magic, but not that magic !

Instead use:

```
$.ajax({url:'/controller/action',success: function(d){ $.blockUI(..., message: d,  ...) }})
```

Comment: Great it works. I pass url and data parameter. $.ajax({ url: 'Gallery/Show', type:"POST", data: "image056.jpg", success... Can you just tell me how can I get this data later?

Comment: What do you mean by get this data later ? Get it from a field ? Use a jquery selector: $("myInputText").val()

Comment: oh add data as a map. { ..., data: { name=value, name2=$("#itemId").val() }, ... }